# How to v-bind content-class in v-checkbox component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In first CodePen example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROXrRZ you can see tooltip message has padding using prop `content-class="pl-5"`

[First picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSzjt.png)

In second CodePen example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwebXR you can see that tooltip message doesn't have it using v-bind on same prop like `:content-class="{'pl-5': true}"`

[Second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqodG.png)

**How to make v-bind work on content-class?**

Comment: As far as I know, object syntax can only be used for `:class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `content-class` prop doesn't accept an object as value.

You can just use the following syntax:

`<v-tooltip top :content-class="condition ? 'pl-5' : ''">`